# MySQL for persistence for SharePoint (WSS)

Tags: mysql, sharepoint, wss

This question has been asked many times in many forums but I haven't seen a confident conclusive answer. So I'll try my luck again.

I want to know whether and how is it possible to use MySQL as the persistence node (configuration and content) for SharePoint. As of now, I am only interested to know about WSS (I guess same would apply to MOSS as well).

Basically I should be able to define lists, document libraries and all content that lives in MySQL.

My front end will be pure ASP.Net and will use WSS APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is most likely to be "**NO**". When you install WSS, it will ask for a Microsoft SQL server and will not allow you to choose other kinds of SQL servers.

WSS/MOSS depends on hundreds of inter-related stored procedures living in Microsoft SQL Server, these are quite technology specific and use Microsoft SQL- only solutions in there.

However, if you do not want to pay for MSSQL Server, you can install WSS/MOSS on [Microsoft SQL Express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/SQL/), this works fine, except you have size limit of 4GB.

Comment: Agreed. There is no chance of using a database other than Microsoft Sql Server for SharePoint. They are too tightly coupled and providing database independence is not in Microsoft's interests. A minor clarification though - MSDE had a 2Gb limit; Sql Server Express has a 4Gb limit.

Comment: Quite sad :( ... Anyhow, does this restriction apply to both configuration & content databases?

Comment: Yes, this especially applies to the configuration database, which is optimized for fast performance (using MSsql specific calls, again)

Comment: Hmm ... so does that mean there is a possibility of the content database to be something other than MS SQL (probably MySQL)?? I guess MS SQL Express Ed. would be okay for configuration database because that is the one that won't really grow but content database would certainly grow.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. All databases, including search database, shared services database, my sites database et cetera, all of them have to be Microsoft SQL. Period.

Comment: Thanks. Not the desired answer, but at least a reason to move on :)

Comment: Little addendum, if you install WSS you don't get the normal MSSQL express edition but a slightly different configuration called "Windows Internal Database". This version does _not_ have the artifical 4GB size limit.